# Union two tables with a table _name column

Tags: sql, ansi-sql

I want to union two tables(Student1, Student2).

1 - **Student1**

```
| student_code |  name   |  
--------------------------
| 1            |  katia  |   
| 2            |  roger  |   
| 3            |  ken    |
```

2 - **Student2**

```
| student_code |  name   |  
--------------------------
| 3            |  katia  |   
| 4            |  roger  |   
| 5            |  ken    |
```

then I want get result like this.

**result**

```
|table_name| student_code |  name   |  
-------------------------------------
|Student1  | 1            |  katia  |   
|Student1  | 2            |  roger  |   
|Student1  | 3            |  ken    | 
|Student2  | 3            |  katia  |   
|Student2  | 4            |  roger  |   
|Student2  | 5            |  ken    |
```

I want to use only ANSI sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 select 'Student1' AS table_name,student_code,name from student1
 union
 select 'Student2' AS table_name,student_code,name from student2
```

I assume you know the difference between`UNION` and `UNION ALL`, `union` brings unique records, it is same as `UNION PERFORMED ON SETS` while `union all` will bring duplicate rows as well.

In your case, it will bring duplicates even with union because of the first column which differentiates the rows.

Comment: Thanks! It was very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You could use

```
SELECT 'Student1' AS table_name, student_code, name FROM Student1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Student2' AS table_name, student_code, name FROM Student2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use UNION ALL statement :

SELECT 'Student1' as table_name, student_code, name FROM Student1
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Student2' as table_name, student_code, name FROM Student2
```